# How to use ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED

Tags: android

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) for ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.

> Stated "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."

How can I use it, to manually call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send that broadcast, as the documentation states.

You are welcome to build your own copy of Android that removes that restriction. You can then package your copy of Android into your own custom ROM and install that ROM on your device. Then, you can send that broadcast.

Comment: is there anyway to detect, that tells application is updated ?

Comment: @UMESH0492: You can **register** a receiver to **listen** for this broadcast. Then you will find out when your application's package is replaced.